# Suppress output to StdOut when piping echo

Tags: bash, unix, echo, pipe

I'm making a bash script that crawls through a directory and outputs all files of a certain type into a text file.  I've got that working, it just also writes out a bunch of output to console I don't want (the names of the files)

Here's the relevant code so far, tmpFile is the file I'm writing to:

```
for DIR in `find . -type d` # Find problem directories
do
        for FILE in `ls "$DIR"` # Loop through problems in directory
        do
                if [[ `echo ${FILE} | grep -e prob[0-9]*_` ]]; then
                        `echo ${FILE} >> ${tmpFile}`
                fi
        done
done
```

The files I'm putting into the text file are in the format described by the regex prob[0-9]*_ (something like prob12345_01)

Where I pipe the output from echo ${FILE} into grep, it still outputs to stdout, something I want to avoid.  I think it's a simple fix, but it's escaping me.

Comment: The safe way to iterate over `find` output is `find ... -print0 | while read -r -d "" DIR`. [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), use `for FILE in "$DIR"/*`. Remove the backticks from the `echo ${FILE} >> ${tmpFile}` line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All this can be done in one single find command. Consider this:

```
find . -type f -name "prob[0-9]*_*" -exec echo {} >> ${tmpFile} \;
```

#### EDIT:

Even simpler: (Thanks to **@GlennJackman**)

```
find . -type f -name "prob[0-9]*_*" >> $tmpFile
```

Comment: I do like this solution, and I see how it works, however it's generating two files, neither containing the correct data. the tmpfile var is actually just TMP_COUNTER, the files I'm getting then are TMP_COUNTER and TMP_COUNTER; (the only diff being the semicolon)

EDIT: Disregard the above, fixed that.  Now the file is simply empty.

Comment: Can you pls try: `find . -type f -name "prob[0-9]*_*" -exec echo {} >> ${tmpFile} \;`

Comment: You don't even need `-exec`: `find . -type f -name "prob[0-9]*_*" -print >> $tmpFile`

Comment: @glennjackman: Agreed, I shouldn't have used exec there. Edited.

Comment: @glennjackman: I have even removed `-print` also since that is by default there.

Comment: Ok, I got that find working from the shell itself, calling it within a bash script prints all the results from the grep to console though

Comment: Realizing that probably makes no sense, I should clarify that I changed the command to this:
find  -type f | egrep prob[0-9]*_ >> ${tmpFile}

Comment: Nevermind, I'm totally off the ball with this.  I had a sort command that was outputting everything.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your specific question, you can pass `-q` to grep for silent output.

```
if echo "hello" | grep -q el; then
  echo "found"
fi
```

But since you're already using find, this can be done with just one command:

```
find . -regex ".*prob[0-9]*_.*" -printf '%f\n' >> ${tmpFile}
```

`find`'s regex is a match on the whole path, which is why the leading and trailing `.*` is needed.

The `-printf '%f\n'` prints the file name without directory, to match what your script is doing.

Answer (score 1):

what you want to do is, `read` the output of the `find` command,
for every entry `find` returned, you want to get all (`*`) the files under that location
and then you want to check whether that filename matches the pattern you want
if it matches then add it to the tmpfile

```
while read -r dir; do
    for file in "$dir"/*; do  # will not match hidden files, unless dotglob is set
        if [[ "$file" =~ prob[0-9]*_ ]]; then
            echo "$file" >> "$tmpfile"
        fi
done < <(find . -type d)
```

however `find` can do that alone
anubhava got me there ;)
so look his answer on how that's done