# Last Occurrence of Character Field Separator AWK

Tags: regex, bash, awk, find

I'm using a find command to find all files of a certain format, that command has been golden.  I'm piping that output into an awk command and I want to use the last underscore as a field separator.  The problem being that depending on the path the file is in, there could be one or two underscores before the fact.

```
find . -regex ".*prob[0-9]*_.*" | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "_.*$" } { print $1 " " $2 }'
```

I get what's wrong with the regular expression in my field separator, it thinks to separate on the underscore and whatever follows, is there away to specify just the single character itself.  Moreover, how do I specifically use a field separator on the last occurrence of a character.

This is somewhat an extension of a question I asked earlier:
[Suppress output to StdOut when piping echo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304594/suppress-output-to-stdout-when-piping-echo)

The files I get are generally like this, the wrinkle being that the directory can have an underscore as well:
/the/directory/probXXXXX_XX

where X is any integer.

A workaround I've been thinking of is separating at every underscore and then print every column... I'd rather like to get it working in the method above though.

Comment: How do you think you would modify the assignment to `FS` to be only `_`, given what is currently being done?

Comment: How do you mean?  I can use FS = "_", but then that separates off an extra underscore and creates a column I don't want.  I only want to separate the last underscore.

Comment: See below for the rest of the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A trick of `awk` that is not obvious is that `$` is an operator; you can use it with a variable or even an expression, and in particular with expressions involving the predefined variable `NF`:  `$NF` gets the last field, `$(NF - 1)` the second last field.

Comment: I'm not sure I get how this will help me separate on the last underscore.  I know I can use $NF to refer to the last column, but that column isn't separated right.

I'm fiddling looping with separating on every underscore and then looping fomr 1 to NF and printing, but this displays it a line at a time.

`for (i=1; i <= NF; i++) print $i`

EDIT: or do I simply need to escape $ on my regex (I'm trying this)

Comment: If you set `FS = "_"` then either the column will be separated correctly or `"_"` isn't actually the column separator.  As to the other, `print` includes a newline; use `printf` to avoid it.

Comment: Alright, well, now I've got another problem (joy), depending on the number of records (there can be 2 or 3 in most situations) I can't format everything properly.

Using modular arithmetic I'm checking for every nth record and then printing the new line, I'm at the point where I've almost got it working.  Is there a way to count the number of characters in a string in awk?

The record $0, the whole string, I want to count the number of underscores in it, that minus 1 is after how many records i want to pritn a newline

Comment: If you've set `FS = "_"` then `NF` is the number of fields, which is the number of underscores plus 1.  If you want to do it for other characters, the easiest way is probably to use the same trick on the result of `split()`.

Comment: Ay, that does it, logic is simply escaping me today.  I need to apologize to my monitor... I may or may not have been screaming at it